# jQuery UI MultiSelect Widget search filter not receiving focus when in a jQuery dialog,

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm having trouble with a jQuery UI MultiSelect widget search filter not receiving focus when in a jQuery dialog.  The issue I'm experiencing can be reproduced by viewing the following HTML page in a browser:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <style media="screen" title="currentStyle" type="text/css">
            @import "styles/jquery.multiselect.css";
            @import "styles/jquery.multiselect.filter.css";
            @import "styles/assets/prettify.css";
            @import "styles/jquery.ui.all.css";
            @import "styles/style.css";
        </style>
        <script src="scripts/jquery-2.0.0.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/assets/prettify.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/jquery.multiselect.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/jquery.multiselect.filter.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input id="create-package" type="button" value="Open Dialog" />
        <div id="package-dialog-form" title="Create new package">
            <p class="validateTips">All form fields are required.</p>
            <form>
                <fieldset>
                    <select multiple="multiple" style="width:370px">
                        <option value="red">Red</option>
                        <option value="green">Green</option>
                        <option value="blue">Blue</option>
                        <option value="orange">Orange</option>
                        <option value="purple">Purple</option>
                        <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
                        <option value="brown">Brown</option>
                        <option value="black">Black</option>
                    </select>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("select").multiselect().multiselectfilter();

                $( "#package-dialog-form" ).dialog({
                    autoOpen: false,
                    height: 360,
                    width: 740,
                    modal: true,
                    buttons: {
                        "Create": function() {
                            var bValid = true;
                            allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
                        },
                        Cancel: function() {
                            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                        }
                    }
                });

                $( "#create-package" ).button().click(function() {
                    $( "#package-dialog-form" ).dialog( "open" );
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Can anyone help me with this issue?  Here's a forked jqfiddle of my issue http://jsfiddle.net/tim_kruger/7ubdE/.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention that I'm using the multiselect widget found here http://www.erichynds.com/blog/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget.

Comment: why don't create a fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Actually didn't think about it as I haven't used fiddle much, will create one in a bit to show my example, thanks for the advice @Felice Pollano.

Comment: Hi @Felice Pollano here is my fiddle url => http://jsfiddle.net/LGzFB/13/.  It's my first time creating a fiddle so be kind LMAO.  I wasn't too sure how to include the external resources into my fiddle example.

Comment: @TimotyKruger you can stick the script inline or use ExternalResources and provide an url

Comment: OK updated jsfiddle => http://jsfiddle.net/LGzFB/20/ @Felice Pollano.

Comment: I did a bit more searching on the net and found these 2 solutions, but they don't seem to be working in my instance, https://github.com/ehynds/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/issues/214 and https://github.com/ehynds/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/issues/397    
Hopefully it'll work for someone else though.  This issue is getting a tab annoying now :(.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a lot of time and research I decided to drop the jQuery UI MultiSelect Widget by Eric Hynds for Chosen - a JavaScript plugin for jQuery and Prototype as this seems to be much more reliable when used with the jQuery UI dialog.  Here is a link for anyone who's also struggling with what I mentioned above and is looking for an alternative:

http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

Comment: Thanks for doing the leg work; this works much better with jQuery UI dialog.

Comment: Hi Timothy..i have a doubt regarding http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/ control...Actually i have two drop down list in one drop down list i am applying http://dropdowncheckboxes.codeplex.com/ control..and in another dropdown list i want to apply ur suggested control..But ur control is not working with http://dropdowncheckboxes.codeplex.com/ this contol..can you help me?

Answer (score 7):

Simply put this lines:

```
if ($.ui && $.ui.dialog && $.ui.dialog.prototype._allowInteraction) {
            var ui_dialog_interaction = $.ui.dialog.prototype._allowInteraction;
            $.ui.dialog.prototype._allowInteraction = function(e) {
                if ($(e.target).closest('.ui-multiselect-filter input').length) return true;
                return ui_dialog_interaction.apply(this, arguments);
            }; 
        }
```

after your

```
$(element).dialog("open");
```

(or after dialog creation if you are using autoOpen:true).

Tested with:

- Jquery UI v1.10.1
- MultiSelect UI Widget 1.13
- MultiSelect UI Widget Filter Plugin 1.5pre

Comment: I can confirm that Nicola's answer was the only one that actually helped us to fix the Multiselect issue. Tried appending the multiselect to the dialog but it did not work.

Comment: @Nicola Do we need to keep this code every where when we use multiselect filter ? Or do we have any better way ? Or can we put this code in multiselect plugin ? Thanks

Comment: Here at work we tend to not modify directly source code (unless severe bug), in order to preserve future compatibility.
In fact this code snippet was written to avoid library modifications. I guess you could put directly in the library tho.

Answer (score 1):

This took me a while to figure out, but with multislelect v.1.14pre you can pass an appendTo option that will fix this problem.

As it stands, the multiselect is appended to body, which means the filter input exists outside of the dialog. AFAIK, jQuery effectively disables inputs outside of an active dialog.

```
var dialogElement = "#myDialog";
$(dialogElement).dialog({
  open: function() {
      $("#myMultiSelectInput").multiselect({
              appendTo : dialogElement
      });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can move a widget into dialog.

```
$('#select').multiselect({
        ...
        open: function () {
            var menu = $(this).multiselect("widget"),
                button = $(this).next(),
                dialog = $('#dialog').dialog('widget');

            menu.css({top: (parseInt(menu.css('top'))-parseInt(dialog.css('top'))-button.height())+'px',
                      left: (parseInt(menu.css('left'))-parseInt(dialog.css('left')))+'px'});
        }}).multiselectfilter({
            ...
        });

    $('#select').multiselect('widget').appendTo($('#dialog'));
```